# Как правильно распространять Java приложение?

Tags: update, java, download, обновление

Основная трудность возникает в необходимости иметь jdk, которая далеко не у всех есть. Вот у меня пример кода для обновления моего приложения:

```
public class UpdateProject extends LongTermOperationThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UpdateProject update = new UpdateProject();
    update.start();
}

@Override
public void run(){
    progressBar.start();
    startUpdate();
    if (!Thread.interrupted()){
        selebrateSuccess();
    } 
    System.exit(1);
}
public void startUpdate(){
    progressBar.setDialogTitle("Выполняется обновление");
    progressBar.setShowResult(true);
    progressBar.setShowDetails(true);
    if (!Thread.interrupted()){
     try {
        File file = new File ("jdk.exe");
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        progressBar.setInscriptions("байтов", "загружено");
        setOperationDetails("Загрузка файла...");
        URL connection = new URL("http://mySite.com/updates/javaMachine/x64/jdk.exe");
        HttpURLConnection urlconn;
        urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
        urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlconn.connect();
        InputStream in = null;
        in = urlconn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("jdk.exe");

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int c = in.read(buffer);
        while (c > 0&&!Thread.interrupted()) {
            updateProgressObjects(c);
            writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
            c = in.read(buffer);

        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        in.close();
        if (Thread.interrupted()){
            File file1 = new File ("jdk.exe");
            if (file1.exists()) file1.delete();
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setInscriptions("файлов", "обновлено");
        progressBar.setDataProgress(false);
        setOperationDetails("Процесс установки java machine...");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Отмена установки");
         finishWithError("Ошибка","Ошибка получения файла jdk");
     }
    }
    if (!Thread.interrupted()){
     try {
        progressBar.setDataProgress(true);
        progressBar.setInscriptions("байтов", "загружено");
        setOperationDetails("Загрузка файла проекта...");
        URL connection = new URL("http://mySite.com/updates/pc-windows/app.jar");
        HttpURLConnection urlconn;
        urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
        urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlconn.connect();
        InputStream in = null;
        in = urlconn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("appTmp.jar");

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int c = in.read(buffer);
        while (c > 0&&!Thread.interrupted()) {
            updateProgressObjects(c);
            writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
            c = in.read(buffer);
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        in.close();
        if (Thread.interrupted()){
            File fileTmp = new File("appTmp.jar");
            if (fileTmp.exists()){
                fileTmp.delete();
                return;         
            }else {
                File file = new File ("app.jar");
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                fileTmp.renameTo(file);
            }
        }
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("app.jar"));
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        finishWithError("Ошибка","Ошибка получения файла app");
     }
    }
}
@Override
public void cancel() {
    interrupt();
}
@Override
public void tryAgain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

В общих чертах обновлялка скачивает установщик jdk и запускает его. Потом скачивает актуальную версию моего приложения, удаляет старую версию и запускает новую.

Проблемы:

1) Приложение запускаетcя до того как jdk установится и я не знаю как отследить окончание установки jdk

2) Нет смысла устанавливать jdk если он уже существует. Лучший вариант, чтоб обновлялка сама проверяла наличие его, но не знаю как так сделать. Или можно спрашивать у пользователя о его наличие.

3) 2 одновременно активных окна (обновлялка и установщика jdk), а потом еще и третье окно выскакивает (с помощью чего открывать jar файл).

В идеале хочу видеть один установщик как windows установщики. В одном окне сразу может ставится Directx, Visual C++ и само приложение.

Comment: Зачем пользователю JDK? JRE достаточно. И обновляется оно самостоятельно, не вижу причин перекладывать эту заботу на своё приложение.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev То есть можно один раз при первом запуске приложения заставить пользователя установить jre, а при обновлении можно только скачивать новую версию и запускать ее?

Comment: Думаю, что не стоит изобретать велосипед, используйте  инсталляторы. Для windows-систем что-нибудь вроде InstallShield, который будет устанавливать идущее в комплекте JRE. Для Linix-систем rpm- и deb-пакеты, которым JRE определено зависимостью.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Стоит InstallShield от 700 баксов конечно жаль-(

Answer (score 2):

Для распространения есть несколько вариантов

- [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [javapackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)

Оба варианта позволяют создавать пакеты под разные ОС со всем необходим для запуска приложения.

Обновлять приложение, вы можете, путем выкачивания измененных классов и сохранения их в домашней директории пользователя. При старте приложения проверяйте их наличие и загружайте.

Answer (score 0):

Верхний уровень абстракции инверсии зависимостей - переход от консольного приложения к веб-клиенту:

- у всех пользователей приложения всегда последняя версия
- нет необходимости обеспечивать переносимость на разные платформы за счет работы представления UI браузере
- выше безопасность данных
- выше контроль разработчика
- проще проводится работа с ошибками (и рассылка обновленных версий)
- и много-много других плюсов.

Comment: Верно это мой следующий шаг. Просто перед переходом хочу почить про JavaScript,а  на это нет времени.